# Why does Siri not set Geofence reminders on iPhone when used in conjuction with an Exchange account?

Tags: iphone, exchange-activesync, siri, reminders

I have been trying to use Siri to set a Geofence reminder to no avail. Apparently there seems to be some type of conflict with the phones local reminders and syncing (via Active sync) with Exchange servers in general. Siri will setup a standard reminder but review of the created task none of the Geofence options are present. I have read through Apple's forums and other 3rd party forumns. I have found a thread on Apple's forum that can be found [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3389585?start=0&tstart=0) that involves turning off reminders and the Exchange account and enabling them on your iCloud account. Upon testing, this potential work around was unsuccessful for me (Siri still refuses to utilize Geofence options). I am currently syncing to an Exchange 2010 server (mail, contacts, calendars and reminders). Can any one provide or point to:

- A canonical answer as to why this occurs?
- Are there any potential workarounds that will allow an Exchange account
  and built in Siri Geofence functionality to work in tandem with
  each other?

The information that I have been able to locate to date reflects conflicting views with some parties saying it can be done and others saying it can't be done. I have yet to find a definitive answer on Apples general site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research is seems as though Siri creates "Tasks" on my Exchange server, which don't allow geofencing. What is needed is an iCloud "Reminder", which does allow for Geofence reminders. You need to set up Reminders to use iCloud by default as follows:

- Make sure your iCloud account is setup online, and enable the same
  iCloud account on your iPhone.
- Make sure that the notifications and calendars are syncing with
  iCloud on your iPhone.

[image: Check iCloud Settings]

Next you will need to navigate to **Settings >> Reminders**:

[image: Select Reminders]

[image: Choose Default List]

[image: Verify Default List is set to iCloud and not Exchange]

Once these steps are completed the reminders functionality (with geofencing alerts) should work properly (even with Exchange). You will obviously need to designate Geo points via a contact entry with address information on the iPhone itself for this to work (i.e. Work, Home, etc..). There is a lot of good information on this question along with a trouble shooting process in this [Apple forum thread located here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3395604?start=0&tstart=0). Please note that this process was tested on an iPhone 5 with iOS 6 (build 10A405) on an AT&T cellular network.

Answer (score 0):

I assume Geofencing isn't available on Exchange as there is no field for it. Can you keep your reminders on the iCloud account instead of on Exchange?

Comment: I have tried to switch my reminders to iCloud and shut off reminders in the Exchange account. The geofencing is still unavailable even after doing so.

Comment: Are location services enabled?